# How to remove specific words from text corpus in R? Code provided to amend

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, quanteda

Suppose you have a corpus, e.g.

```
myCorpus <- c("Carles werwa went to sadaf buy trsfr in the supermanket", 
           "Marta needs to werwa sadaf go to Jamaica")
```

I have a dictionary (`data_int_syllables`) containing a list of words which I could like to remove from `mytext`.

Using `library('quanteda')`, I tried the following:

```
myTokens <- tokens(myCorpus, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE)
myTokens <- tokens_select(myTokens, names(data_int_syllables))
```

The issue is, this code amends `myTokens` to keep only the tokens found in an English dictionary (`data_int_syllables`). Instead, I want to remove all words found in `data_int_syllables`.

Does anyone know how to adjust the code so that the words are removed, rather than kept?

Comment: Use `tokens_select(myTokens, names(data_int_syllables), selection = "remove")` or `tokens_remove(myTokens, names(data_int_syllables))`

Comment: @phiver thanks! Do you know if it's also possible to remove specific words from a dfm? E.g. if you has `politicians_dfm <- dfm(corpus_subset(politicians_corpus, President == 'Obama'),
              remove = stopwords('english'))`. Is there a method within this like `tokens_remove` where you can remove e.g. words from a dictionary?

Comment: `dfm_remove` or `dfm_select(x, selection = "remove")` You can use a dictionary, regex, etc etc. Read the help with `dfm_remove` / `dfm_select`.